# Font-Size Change Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a header which changes size on scroll  within my website I am coding. However I need to change the font size of the text within the header. I am able to get it to go smaller with the following code. Below that I have the relvant CSS.

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function(e) {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value < 100 )
        $("header").css("height", "100px");
    else
        $("header").css("height", "55px");
        $('h1').css({'font-size' : '30px'});
});
```

That makes it go smaller just until you refresh

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 75px;
    width: 100vw;
    color: #212121;
    padding-top: 2vh;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding-left: 1vw;
    font-weight: 300;
    z-index: 30;
}
```

Though if I try to make it so it resets to it's original fontsize (code below) when you scroll back up it messes up the JS and none of the JS on the page works.

```js
$(document).on('scroll', function(e) {
    var value = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ( value < 100 )
        $("header").css("height", "100px");
        $('h1').css({'font-size' : '75px'});
    else
        $("header").css("height", "55px");
        $('h1').css({'font-size' : '30px'});
});
```

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the console?

Comment: can you add it in fiddle?

Comment: If you add `{}` on around your if-else statements you might detect the error yourself. The second statements in your if-else is not executed as part of a block. The if-else only executes one statement which does not include you font-resizing.

Comment: @E.Sundin indeed, the code is syntactically incorrect, so there'd be errors as soon as it's loaded.

Comment: @E.Sundin Yeah that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use JS and not CoffeeScript, you need add quotes `if { ... } else { ... }`

running example https://jsfiddle.net/pmgy9ar2/